# request.POST.get() doesn't work when I pass context to the view

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe for my django site to accept one-off payments. The following code works fine and the `charge` is successfull:

```
def pay(request):
    # Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    # See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
    stripe.api_key = "sk_test_exhH8mdKfkXkaxzvtVphJOBZ"

    # Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
    # Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
    if request.POST.get('stripeToken'):
        print(request.POST)
        token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')

        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=999,
            currency='usd',
            description='Boosted Post',
            source=token,
        )
        print('Charge:', charge)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        print('NO')

    context = {
        'amount': 999,
    }

    return render(request, 'advertising/pay.html', context)
```

however if I add context to this view, it doesn't work (`if request.POST.get('stripeToken')` doesn't fire):

```
def post_ad(request):
    boost_form = AdvertisePostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if boost_form.is_valid():
        instance = boost_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.total_price = ad_price(instance.position, instance.duration)
        instance.ad = True
        instance.save()
        context = {
            'hash': instance.hash,
        }
        return pay(request, context)
    else:
        pass

    context = {
        'boost_form': boost_form
    }
    return render(request, 'advertising/post_ad.html', context)


def pay(request, context):
    ad = get_object_or_404(AdvertisePost, hash=context['hash'])
    amount = ad.total_price * 100

    # Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    # See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
    stripe.api_key = "sk_test_exhH8mdKfkXkaxzvtVphJOBZ"

    # Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
    # Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
    if request.POST.get('stripeToken'):
        print(request.POST)
        token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')

        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=amount,
            currency='usd',
            description='Boosted Post',
            source=token,
        )
        print('Charge:', charge)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        print(request.POST)
        print('NO')

    context = {
        'amount': amount,
        'ad': ad
    }

    return render(request, 'advertising/pay.html', context)
```

Any idea why this is and how I can fix it?

Here is the stripe form if you are curious:

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_8rSK77eA02iovefCmQCeV9su"
    data-amount="{{ amount }}"
    data-name="My name"
    data-description="Example charge"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-currency="aud">
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Check for console errors? Can you also share the POST request headers?

Comment: Also check if `data-amount` is set correctly on the rendered HTML

Comment: the `request.POST` when the page loads (in the `else` section) is the data from the form in `post_ad()`: `<QueryDict: {'entered_category': ['test'], 'title': ['test title'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['gZmm2xxIw2BbQpNtrVIjFVttcRqim8hYEqROGx9lQll502zT1mWfsyRVRcddITdS']}>` And I can confirm `data-amount` is the correct amount rendered in the html

Comment: When I submit the stripe form, my terminal fires a `"POST /advertise/post/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16988` - however it doesn't fire either of the if/else sections in the view.

Comment: My guess is that `AdvertisePostForm.valid()` fails; and you get into the else block with a `pass`, avoiding the `pay` codeblock call entirely.

Comment: Also a word of advice; POST request should always do a `HttpResponseRedirect` to prevent form resubmission. Also when using function-based views, it is best practice to separate your code into two blocks for handling `if request.method == 'GET'` and `if request.method == 'POST'`